# ASP.Net OWIN authentication with facebook

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, authentication, owin

I am following [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) for setting up authentication on my site using facebook and google. While I can get authenticated using any number of test google accounts; for facebook, I can only login using the account in which I created the app id and the app secret key. This is also mentioned in that article on point #9. 
 The error message I get when I use any other test facebook accounts I created for the purpose of testing is:

App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.

So now suppose I deploy my site online, how will I be able to allow any random facebook user to login? I cannot predict who will be using my site and add them all as test accounts. What is the approach to take to use the asp.net mvc OWIN framework and get this working for facebook authentication like it works for google?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option on the Facebook backend called "Status and Review".  You will then see this prompt:

**Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?**

Set this to "YES" and it should allow any FB account.

Comment: looks like I need to first publish my application as live after going through and passing their tests. There is a submission involved before hand. I suppose they wont agree to my 'for learning purposes' on my personal website reason. Anyways, marking your answer as it pointed me in the right direction.